# If $f \in \mathcal{C}([a,b])$ exactly one local minimum $x^*$, then $a \le x_1 < x_2 \le x^* \implies f(x_1) > f(x_2)$

Tags: calculus

> Show that if a continuous function $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has exactly one local minimum, then $$a \le x_1 < x_2 \le x^* \implies f(x_1) > f(x_2)$$ and $$x^* \le x_1 < x_2 \le b \implies f(x_2) > f(x_1).$$

By drawing I can easily see that a function with only one local minimum has to have a form like $f(x) = x^2$. Could you please give me a hint on how to start formally proving this?

Comment: It’s probably true if $f$ is of “bounded variation.” But I think there might be nasty examples where $x$ has a local minimum but not have this property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof by contradiction. If $f(x_1)\le f(x_2)$ then let $c=\arg_x\min_{a\le x\le x_2}f(x)$ be the minimum of the continuous function $f$ on the closed interval $[a,x_2]$. If $c=x_2$ then there exist at least one more point of minimum, $x_1$,  which is a second local minimum besides $x^*$, contradiction. If $c<x_2$ then $c$ itself is a second point of local minimum, contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try proving it by contradiction. Assume there exist $a\leq x_1 < x_2 \leq x^*$ such that $f(x_1)\leq f(x_2)$ and then prove that, in that case, there has to be a local minimum between $x_1$ and $x_2$.